# List of button in Android

Tags: android, list, view

I want to make a list of ImageButtons in an Activity with three buttons in each row. If I make  this with XML (considering there are over 100 buttons) eclipse complains that there are to many views.

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Create buttons dynamically.

Comment: @Hardy is right. You also could use ListView with an adapter. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Are you actually creating hundreds of buttons in one xml file? why not use a list-view, and create the three button layout once for all the cells?

Answer (score 8):

I think you should make buttons dinamically.. like this

```
Button[] btnWord = new Button[num];
 LinearLayout linear;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.dynamicview);
  test();
 }
 private void test() {  
  linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
  for (int i = 0; i < btnWord.length; i++) {
   btnWord[i] = new Button(this);
   btnWord[i].setHeight(50);
   btnWord[i].setWidth(50);
   btnWord[i].setTag(i);
   btnWord[i].setOnClickListener(btnClicked);
   linear.addView(btnWord[i]);
  }
 }
 OnClickListener btnClicked = new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   Object tag = v.getTag();
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 };
```

you can change the number of button array

```
Button[] btnword = new Button[num];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should consider using `GridView`.

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html