# List of buttons

Tags: android

I got 100 ImageButton, I need to make a list of these button, I tried with a static list like the scrollview, It work but the app need 4 to 5 seconds to load all the ImageButtons, so I want to try to make a list that load buttons when user scroll down. In this way the app does not have to load all the buttons at once, I've been looking for a solution for days but I can not find it, someone know how to achieve this list of imagebutton?

Comment: Examples for ListViews are abundant. So finding one is easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of button in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088317/list-of-button-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

You should use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. I recommend starting with some lessons:[List view](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/). Ask if you will have some problems.